# How to put figure between items on enumerate list?

Tags: list, latex, enumerate

I have an `enumerate` list and some items have figures. My code follows below:

```latex
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Estado da arte: 
    \item Levantar os requisitos
    \item Com o microcontrolador
\ref{figurametodo3}.    
    \begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./dados/figuras/metodo_3}
            \caption{Sistema para leitura da identificação de uma Tag} 
            \label{figurametodo3}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \item Estudar
            
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{./dados/figuras/metodo_4}
        \caption{Comunicação entre o microcontrolador e o celular} 
        \label{figurametodo4}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
    
    \item Desenvolver 
    
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./dados/figuras/metodo_final}
        \caption{Comunicação entre celulares e servidor} 
        \label{figura22}
    \end{center}
\end{figure}
            
\end{enumerate}
```

However it aligns all the figures below the list: outside of the places that I want. I want that my figures stay just below that item:  within the list.

Answer (score 13):

This is covered in the following FAQs:

- [How to influence the position of float environments like `figure` and `table` in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)
- [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764)
- [Force LaTeX image to appear in the section in which it's declared](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32598/5764)

Here's one option using the [`float` package](//ctan.org/pkg/float) and it's `[H]`ERE float specifier:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{float,graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{A figure caption}
  \end{figure}

  \item Item 4

  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width = .5\linewidth]{example-image-b}
    \caption{B figure caption}
  \end{figure}

  \item Item 5
  \item Item 6
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [minipage](https://www.tug.org/texinfohtml/latex2e.html#minipage) environment to insert the image:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Estado da arte:
  \item Levantar os requisitos
  \item
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
      Com o microcontrolador \newline                                
      \includegraphics[scale=0.6]{./dados/figuras/metodo_3}
      \captionof{figure}{Sistema para leitura da identificação de    uma Tag}
    \end{minipage}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

You should not use `figure`, if you don't want a float.

The [LaTeX Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) explains:

> Floats are containers for things in a document that cannot be broken
>   over a page. LaTeX by default recognizes "table" and "figure" floats,
>   [...].
>   Floats are there to deal with the problem of the object that won't fit
>   on the present page, and to help when you really don't want the object
>   here just now.

To provide a caption outside of figures one needs to use package [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption), which provides the `captionof` command.

There is also a [capt-of](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/capt-of/capt-of.pdf) package if you are just interested in using the command `\captionof`.

Answer (score 2):

The [answer by Werner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51033520/10871073) is nice but you do have to type in the mandatory "Item 3" besides the "\item" command, for example. Supposing you just want to include a figure on an item on the list without adding any text, there is the following dirty trick:

```
\item \phantom{text}

\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Image}
```

Note that the blank space between these two lines of code is absolutely necessary. In case you want more space between the item label and the diagram, the following could be done:

```
\item \phantom{text} 
\vspace{3mm}
    
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Image}
```

Comment: Can you explain why this trick works?